# Mongodb run a query on $sample result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've a situation where I need to find how many documents match a certain query out of 10000 random documents.

Mongodb's $sample aggregation seems to be an efficient way to obtain random documents.

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 3 } } ]
)
```

But how can I run a query on the returned result?

I can obtain random ids via $sample and the do another query with $in for those ids, but I'm trying to learn if there is a simple way.

**Update:** 
**More information**

Other than "_id" and "email" fields other fields are user defined, like in customer.io you can add/remove other attributes.

```
  person

  {
  _id: "..."
  email : "email@email.com"
  facebook: "facebook page url"
  ... and lot of other fields which may be present or not depending on the person



  }
```

The query is also going to be generated by user, but for simplicity lets say:
  ***after selecting random 10000 documents*** I want to run

```
find({facebook: {$exists: true} })
```

on those selected documents.

Comment: can you add a sample document from your `users` collection and the query you are paliing to run after the **`$sample`** stage ?

Comment: @felix added more information

Comment: The answer posted by p.streef is actually the right one. First get 10000 random documents with `{$sample: {$size: 10000}}`, and then filter thoses documents with `{$match: {facebook: {$exists: true}}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add a `$match` statement

```
db.users.aggregate([ 
{ $sample: { size: 3 } },
{ $match: { facebook: {$exists : true} } },
{ $count: "nr_matches" }
])
```

read more on aggregation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

edit: 
or even shorter

```
db.users.aggregate([ 
{ $sample: { size: 3 } },
{ $group: { _id : {facebook : {$exists : true}}, count : {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

Comment: thanks, but that returns random documents $matching the query. I want to select random 10000 documents and then find out how many of those 10000 match the query i want.

Comment: nice, I didn't understand that order of the $sample and $match make the difference. thanks a lot